# How to apply Parent Category to Child Category Products in Magento 1.x

Tags: magento, categories

How can I apply Parent Category to it's Sub Category Products? (Magento 1.x)
For example:

> **DEFAULT CATEGORY**
>  CLOTHING 
>    - Tops (shirt1)
>
> **sku - category**
>  shirt1 - Tops 
>  shirt2 - Tops 
>  shirt3 - Tops

my goal is to apply "CLOTHING" category (*which is the parent category*) to "shirt1, shirt2 & shirt3" like this:

> **sku - category**
>  shirt1 - Tops, CLOTHING 
>  shirt2 - Tops, CLOTHING 
>  shirt3 - Tops, CLOTHING

without using csv or going to Admin Panel > Catalog > Manage Categories > ***Category*** > Category Products > Manually looking and applying products

Comment: How are you hoping to do this? Code? PHP? SQL? Or something else?

Answer (score 2):

I have create this code. i have not used yet but definitely works for you.

Just execute below script from root

```
require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app();

$pro_ids = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->getAllIds();
foreach($pro_ids as $pro_id){
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($pro_id);
    $categories = $product->getCategoryIds(); $save = 0;
    foreach($categories as $categorie){
        $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categorie);
        foreach ($category->getParentCategories() as $parent) {
            if(!in_array($parent->getId(), $categories)){
                $categories[] = $parent->getId(); $save = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    if($save == 1){
        $product->setCategoryIds($categories);
        $product->save();
    }
}
```

Please check this and let me know in case of any query.

Thanks

Comment: Thank you Mayur jadeja, I'll test this and keep you posted, thanks again :)

Comment: Hi glastiva is this solution worked for you? please let me know if you need any further help thanks again,

Comment: Hi glastiva is this solution worked for you? is this solution work for you can you please provide your feedback and provide your vote.